# R: "unused argument" in levels

Tags: r, levels, unused-variables

I used read_excel to import my data and filter the table for a value out of a column. So far so good.

Next, to be able to work with the values from a different column (I think?), the person that wrote this code used as.factor as follows:

`filtered_table$column<-as.factor(filtered_table$column, levels = c("name1", "name2",...))`

after running, this returns

> "Error in as.factor((filtered_table$column, levels = c("name1",.... :
> unused argument (levels = c("name1", "name2", ...)

None of the names I entered are being recognized as arguments, they're very simple and I checked the spelling. I'm not looking to drop unused levels, since there are none, to begin with. The names that were in their place originally were also strings. How do I fix this?

Comment: Difficult to say for sure without a complete, self-contained example, but I can tell you that `as.factor()` doesn't have an argument `levels`. You can check this yourself by looking at the documentation in `?as.factor`. Perusing that page would suggest that perhaps the original author meant `factor` and not `as.factor`. Again, just guessing without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page`?as.factor` it shows that the function only takes one argument (in your case the `filtered_table$column`), and therefore the error message indicates that there's not another argument to match up with the second one you've specified in the function call. To specify the levels explicitly, you may need to use the `factor()` function.